# Display jQuery fadein upon successful POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to display a the following div (via fadeIn/fadeOut) when a user saves data in a form.

```
// Display a notification if the save is successful.
$('<div class="save-alert">The current scenario has been saved.</div>')
    .insertAfter($('#main'))
    .fadeIn('slow')
    .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 3000)
    .fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Currently, I submitting the form using the Html.BeginForm helper. Because of this, my entire page is posted, and I cannot display the above notification. I realize I could use the Ajax.BeginForm, but then I run into other problems (namely, not being able to do `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = scenario.ScenarioID });` after I save the scenario).

Does anybody have any suggestions for something else I could try to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to avoid going an ajax route.  If so, just put the message string in a cookie and test for the presence of a message in your view.  If there is a message, display it.  Since it is in a cookie you can retrieve the message even if you redirect after processing a successful post.  Make sure to clear the cookie after you show the message!

We've formalized this process at my company and refer to it as the "Flash" (like Ruby on Rails used to, or maybe still does).

Ideally you could wrap the message setting, retrieval and display logic into a helper class to abstract its implementation from your view.  That way you could use cookies, viewdata or even session values and your views and controllers would not have to change behavior.

Comment: I wouldn't mind going the Ajax route, but I run into some major problems when doing that. (As I said in my post, I can't do a RedirectToAction() which I need to do after submission.)

Comment: Then my approach will work for your case, no need to use ajax and you can still do your redirect.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `jquery.post()` to serve up a background post to prevent the page from reloading.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: this is what Ajax.BeginForm does.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just deny the submit and do it via AJAX:

```
$('#form').submit(function()
{
  return false;

  $.post('test.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data)
  {
    //Do your stuff. Data is the POST response data.
  });
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: That is what the Ajax.BeginForm is doing.

Comment: What is it? I thought this was jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Return the URL, and redirect on the client side. You could use a `JsonResult` or other to send data in MVC back to the client.

Comment: @JasCav - this is similar. In your case though you might just use a success function instead of a target update id. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCPreview4UsingAjaxAndAjaxForm.aspx